# use PHP to echo a message on a z-index above slideshow in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

---

I have been trying to echo a message in a slideshow that is a plugin in WordPress. However, no matter what I do I can not get it to work. What have I done wrong? it should be possible to echo this message in a plugin. The plugin's name is Photo Gallery

```html
 <div id="bwg_slideshow_image_container_<?php echo $bwg; ?>" class="bwg_slideshow_image_container_<?php echo $bwg; ?>" >
        <!-- Changed Added popup -->
        <?php
        if($host == 'https://www.artists.com/#') {
    echo $this->__('<div style="width: 200px; height:100px; top: 50px; left: 20px; position:absolute; z-index: 3,000; background-color: #fff; color: #000;"> Please click on the arrow at the bottom of the page for additional information</div>');
}         ?>
        <!-- Changed end added -->
```

Comment: Could you share the code that you do have so we can see what it is that is not working for you?

Comment: I added the code titled "Changed Added popup" that's it. The WordPress plugin is called Photo Gallery has a long complicated code so I could not present it here. Plus I am trying to keep the site secure. The WordPress plugin can be found at WordPress.org

Comment: have you got no output from it at all?